# Cannot run flutter application on first run, gradle error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have created a new flutter app and I cannot get it to run for the first time. It gets stuck at running Gradle task assembleDebug. This is the error message I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> NDK at C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have ran flutter doctor and this are the results

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.804], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.0 at C:\dev\flutter
    • Framework revision 60bd88df91 (2 days ago), 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi 6 (mobile) • a28707477d26 • android-arm    • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome       • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.190
    • Edge (web)       • edge         • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.81

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Base from the error, the NDK build in your machine can't be used. One way to resolve this issue is by deleting the current NDK and have Flutter download a new NDK build. Head over to the NDK path provided in the error and delete `ndk-bundle` folder, then run `flutter clean` in the terminal. Running the app again should automatically run `flutter pub get` to rebuild all the references and dependencies.